# Oracle: find Block session in the past

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I had a problem with session of DB in the past.
My problem is i have some session of DB blocked in the past 4 day.
I want to trace why those session blocked to fixed it.
I tried many way and searching in Google to a achieved this purpose not no hope.

I looked up in table:

> V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY, dba_hist_active_sess_history,sys.WRH$_ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY

But no clue.

Please help me solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?  What, specifically, didn't work?

Are you saying that there are no rows in `dba_hist_active_sess_history` where `blocking_session` is non-NULL?  At least during the time frame that you are interested in)?  Are there other rows in the table for that time frame?  If there are, why are you confident that the sessions were actually blocked in the database (which I assume here means waiting for a lock in the database)?